# Update column same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a problem when I try to update a value in a row database. I need update (add 1 hour) to especifics users in a USER table.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(dateOfBirth, INTERVAL 1 HOUR), dateOfBirth 
from USER 
where dateOfBirth like '%23:00:00%';
```

But when I execute the next UPDATE, show a error

```
UPDATE USER
set dateOfBirth = DATE_ADD(dateOfBirth, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
where id in (select u.id FROM USER u where u.dateOfBirth like '%23:00:00%');
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'USER' for update in FROM clause
```

It's possible execute this sentence with other way?

Comment: `USER` is a reserved mysql keyword

Comment: Does a date of birth need a time ? Maybe a DATE type would make a few things simpler

Comment: The more I look at what is being done here the more it looks like a fix for something that happened due to a timezone or summer/winter clock change time hiccup. So just make the column a DATE type and avoid this hiccup happening again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery in the update is not required.

```
UPDATE USER
set dateOfBirth = DATE_ADD(dateOfBirth, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
where dateOfBirth like '%23:00:00%';
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
UPDATE USER
SET dateOfBirth = DATE_ADD(dateOfBirth, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
WHERE dateOfBirth like '%23:00:00%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the `id` unique in the table?  If so:

```
update user u
    set dateOfBirth = DATE_ADD(dateOfBirth, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
where time(u.dateOfBirth) = '23:00:00';
```

Note that the `dateOfBirth` is apparently a date/time column (why it contains a time I don't understand).  So, date/time functions are more appropriate for the comparison.

Comment: *"why it contains a time I don't understand"* What if you need to calculate precise age calculation? Annyhow + 1

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland I would love to know of a situation where my age needs to be know that accurately :) :) But then I am an old git

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly in the hospital maybe or was your comment meant as a rhetorical question :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . The column is called *dateOfBirth*.  Things called dates should be dates.  And, especially with something like "date of birth" it is really misleading to have a time component in the column.  If this is a hospital, then `DatetimeOfBirth` would be appropriate.

Comment: Looking at what the query is doing I would hazzard a guess that this is a fix for a timezone or clock change issue that would not be an issue for a DATE column :)

Comment: Gorden and @RiggsFolly we all take this way to literal, i geuss :-)  but your are right `DatetimeOfBirth ` would be more appropriate